# dbwriteTable() seems to drop and recreate table

Tags: sql, r

I'm writing data into a table in a Vertica DB from R. I'm using package DBI and RJDBC to perform this operation. I connect to DB, verify if table contains data, delete it and rewrite other data on it.

This is the script

```
    tryCatch({verticaConn =dbConnect(vDriver, "jdbc:vertica://****/company", "***", "****")},
       error=function(e)
       {
         Logging("error",paste("Error conncecting to Vertica:",e))
       })
data<-data.frame(x=c(1,2,3),y=c(1,2,3))



 query<-"SELECT * FROM ESPDM.QUOTAZIONI_R_OUTPUT LIMIT 5"

  get_query = dbGetQuery(verticaConn,query)

  if (nrow(get_query)>0)

  {
    query<-"DELETE FROM QUOTAZIONI_R_OUTPUT"
    get_query = dbSendUpdate(verticaConn,query)


  }
dbWriteTable(verticaConn, "QUOTAZIONI_R_OUTPUT", 
                   as.data.frame(data))
```

The script works great but it seems that table is being dropped and recreate every time this script run which it's not acceptable in this case since other people are reading from this table and they lose the grant every time table is created. 
Thanks

Comment: From what I have read, `DELETE` by itself should not be dropping and recreating a table in Vertica.  Are you sure that there is not some other process at work here?

Comment: Pretty sure, no other process at work.

Comment: Not using Vertica, I wondered if a DELETE without a WHERE might drop the table but they are explicit it does not https://www.vertica.com/docs/9.2.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Statements/DELETE.htm?TocPath=SQL%20Reference%20Manual%7CSQL%20Statements%7C_____64

Comment: Maybe you should try "DELETE * FROM x"

Comment: When I try your suggestion: Error in .verify.JDBC.result(r, "Unable to retrieve JDBC result set for ",  : 
  Unable to retrieve JDBC result set for DELETE * FROM ESPDM.TEST ([Vertica][VJDBC](4856) ERROR: Syntax error at or near "*")

Comment: From Vertica logs, Problems seems to be in dbWriteTable... it drops and recreate table every time is executed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer: you need to specify append=TRUE and overwrite=FALSE. If you only specify append=TRUE and not overwrite=FALSE it doesn't work as expected.

```
dbWriteTable(verticaConn, "QUOTAZIONI_R_OUTPUT", 
                   as.data.frame(data),append=TRUE,overwrite=FALSE)
```